# Fetching data from firestore in angular app type error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs6

I am trying to retrieve a collection from firebase that are called "availableExercises". I am using rxjs 6 and when I am mapping over and assigning the values in an object, I am getting a few errors.

Somehow the app still runs, but I am very confused about this error.

My exercise model is as follows:

```
export interface Exercise {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  duration: number;
  calories: number;
  date?: Date;
  state?: 'completed' | 'cancelled' | null;
}
```

Here is my function I am calling:

```
 fetchAvailableExercises() {
    this.db
      .collection('availableExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(docArray => {
          return docArray.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.payload.doc.id,
              name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
              duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
              calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
        this.availableExercises = exercises;
        this.exercisesChanged.next([...this.availableExercises]);
      });
  }
```

There errors when I run ng serve are:

```
ERROR in src/app/training/training.service.ts(26,44): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/training/training.service.ts(27,48): error TS2339: Property 'duration' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/training/training.service.ts(28,48): error TS2339: Property 'calories' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.1.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

if I `console.log(doc.payload.doc.data());`
I get the expected data as an object like so:
`{calories: 8, duration: 60, name: "Burpees"}`

Comment: if you console.log(doc) are you getting the record?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Yes I am receiving what I am expecting, doc is an object from firebase with a payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscription is expecting an array of `Exercise` objects but it's instead getting an array of generic objects.

Instead of doing `return {`, create an object of type `Exercise` and return that.

```
let exercise: Exercise = {
  id: doc.payload.doc.id,
  name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
  duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
  calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
};
return exercise;
```

I also recommend defining a type on your collection.

```
this.db.collection<Exercise>('availableExercises')
```

Comment: Defining a type onto the collection seems to be the fix I needed.